# Why is there href decoration next to my div?

Tags: html, css, href, text-decorations

Why is there an underline after the text in the image below?

[image: AOrUb92]

```html
<a href="index.html">
    <div style="display: inline-block">
        <img src="images/fallout.svg">
        <h1 class="header_text">Mods</h1>
    </div>
</a>
```

```css
.header_text {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white; 
}
```

Comment: @RyanBemrose the user doesn't have enough rep to include images, and all images uploaded via SO and stored by imgur.

Comment: It is a whitespace. Remove the newlines or hide the underline with css as in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: revised my answer because I didn't understand the question.

to get rid of underlines in hyperlinks, use the following code:

```
#example {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

hyperlinks have a text decoration of "underline" by default. You have to specify "none" to get rid of that.

Comment: Thanks! I added text-decoration: none to the a href and it worked.